# Value of alpha in gensim word-embedding (Word2Vec and FastText) models?

Tags: python-3.x, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding, fasttext

I just want to know the effect of the value of alpha in gensim `word2vec` and `fasttext` word-embedding models? I know that alpha is the `initial learning rate` and its default value is `0.075` form Radim blog.

What if I change this to a bit higher value i.e. 0.5 or 0.75? What will be its effect? Does it is allowed to change the same? However, I have changed this to 0.5 and experiment on a large-sized data with D = 200, window = 15, min_count = 5, iter = 10, workers = 4 and results are pretty much meaningful for the word2vec model. However, using the fasttext model, the results are bit scattered, means less related and unpredictable high-low similarity scores.

Why this imprecise result for same data with two popular models with different precision? Does the value of `alpha` plays such a crucial role during building of the model?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default starting `alpha` is `0.025` in gensim's Word2Vec implementation.

In the stochastic gradient descent algorithm for adjusting the model, the effective `alpha` affects how strong of a correction to the model is made after each training example is evaluated, and will decay linearly from its starting value (`alpha`) to a tiny final value (`min_alpha`) over the course of all training.

Most users won't need to adjust these parameters, or might only adjust them a little, after they have a reliable repeatable way of assessing whether a change improves their model on their end tasks. (I've seen starting values of `0.05` or less commonly `0.1`, but never as high as your reported `0.5`.)

Comment: Thanks, gojomo. I was expecting this answer. Okay, I will also go with alpha value as 0.1 or within it. 1 query, does it is mandatory to specify the model.train() parameter. What happen if I don't  use it after building the model?  If I use the model.train parameter, what could be the desired values for model.train() parameter, after building the model with a certain size, window, iter and min_count values.

Comment: I have computed the similarity between two words, without using model.train() values. Does it is mandatory  to specify model.train() values?

Comment: I wouldn't change the `alpha` default until after everything else is working, & you have a good way to evaluate your models to see if changing `alpha` helps.

Comment: All models must be trained to be useful, but if you supplied the corpus iterable in the model constructor, it will have automatically done the training. If you didn't supply a corpus, you'll have to do the vocabulary-initialization (with method `build_vocab()`) and then training (with method `train()`) yourself. The docs for `train()` are clear about what parameters must be supplied: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.train

Comment: Yeah! Changing of alpha value to 0.5 gives me some meaningful desired sensed results.

Comment: What is corpus iterable? Does It means tokenized words specified as sentences in a nested list or something else?

Comment: I'm am surprised a starting `alpha` of `0.5` is working, that's very far from usual values. Is that really better than just leaving it at its `0.025` default? How much data (total number of examples and average size in words of each example) are you using? What method of evaluating their quality are you using?

Comment: The corpus iterable object is the `sentences` parameter – optional in the class constructor. For `Word2Vec`, it should be an iterable sequence of lists-of-tokens. If provided to the class constructor, all vocabulary-discovery and training will happen automatically – you won't then need to call `train()`. (If you have more questions, you should expand your question with a clear excerpt of the code you're using.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185400/discussion-between-m-s-and-gojomo).